# ng-click in parent div also in child div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've the following code:

```
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Name___</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="app in apps"
                ng-click="go('/editApp/' + plugin.name);">

                <td>
                    <span>{{app.name}}</span>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 100px;">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" 
                              ng-click="openPopup(app)"></i>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

When I click on the OpenPopup, also the go() method firing, how can I do that, If I click on popup just the popup will fire?

Comment: remove the `ng-click` from `tr`

Comment: Well, if you click a child element you've actually clicked its parent too. This is called **event propagation**, in particular **event bubbling**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This executing because your `<td>` nested in `<tr>`, and click firstly fired `openPopup()`

then fired `go()`. You can use `$event.stopPropagation()` for stop event propagation to `<tr>`.
Try

```
        <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Name___</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="app in apps"
            ng-click="go('/editApp/' + plugin.name);">

            <td>
                <span>{{app.name}}</span>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 100px;">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" 
                          ng-click="openPopup(app);$event.stopPropagation()"></i>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Excellent! Worked well.